# im try to do laplacian_pyramid_blending and im getting a wired out put

Tags: image, scikit-image

def laplacian_pyramid_blending(imageA, imageB, mask):
levels = 6
# Construct Laplacian pyramids for images A and B
la = tuple(pyramid_laplacian(imageA, downscale=levels, preserve_range=True, channel_axis=2))
lb = tuple(pyramid_laplacian(imageB, downscale=levels, preserve_range=True, channel_axis=2))

```
# Construct a Gaussian pyramid for the mask
gm = tuple(pyramid_gaussian(mask, downscale=levels, preserve_range=True, channel_axis=2))

# Create the blended Laplacian pyramid Lc
lc = []
for k in range(levels-1):
    lc.append(gm[k]*la[k]+(1-gm[k])*lb[k])

# Sum all levels in Lc to get the blended image
blended_image = lc[0]
for i in lc[1:]:
    i = resize(i, blended_image.shape)
    blended_image += i

return blended_image
```

i was a expecting a full rgb image